# AES.decrypt not working after upgrading react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, cryptojs, metro-bundler

After updating our react native from 0.63.3 to 0.66,

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedString, key)
```

is returning invalid data. We are able to isolate that this is related to metro + babel dependencies but not able to find a workaround. Is this related to metro bundler from 0.56.0 to 0.65.0?
USing:

```
 react-native-crypto-js
```

Comment: We have been facing the issue after updating our react native version recently. Can someone help here please ?